# Integrating React Build file inside Django project

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-router, django-templates

I have been building web apps using NextJS and Django for some time. But recently, my boss gave me the requirements for using ReactJS and using the build files inside Django as templates. Now, I have never tried it before, but according to this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F9o4GSkSo40), it is possible.

But my question is, should I do it? Would I face any performance issues in the future if I do this? Or will there be any bugs or issues related to routing?

I know I can try it myself, but I am looking for some expert advice from senior developers.

Comment: Isn't NextJS just react with SSR? Is the requirement to switch from react server-side-rendering to delivering a single page app and render it all client-side? What is the impetus for this? (*that's probably a question for your boss or whomever is requesting this change*)

Comment: The requirement is to use Create-React-App not NextJs. Boss told me to use CRA because NextJs doesn't give us an html file.